# ssh paramiko cannot read output

Tags: python, linux

I am connecting to a server using `paramiko` and I'm trying to use `channel.send` to receive a sequential output. The script below fails to catch the output from `channel.recv`. Any ideas?

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx",username='kshk',password='xxxxxxxx',key_filename='/home/krisdigitx/.ssh/id_rsa')
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
channel.send('df -h\n')

while channel.recv_ready():
    outp = channel.recv(1024)
print outp
```

Gives:

```
krisdigitx@krisdigitx-Dell-System-XPS-L702X:~/SCRIPTS$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print outp
NameError: name 'outp' is not defined
```

ruuning the script in interpreter mode works...

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx",username='kshk',password='xxxxx',key_filename='/home/krisdigitx/.ssh/id_rsa')
>>> channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
>>> channel.send('df -h\n')
6
>>> while  channel.recv_ready():
...     outp = channel.recv(1024)
... 
>>> print outp
/dec/sda
                      7.2T  6.6T  622G  92% /tmp/xxx
[kshk@server ~]$ 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you define outp in the scope of the context manager that you create with the with statement. 
try printing inside the suite of the context manager i.e.

```
while channel.recv_ready():
    outp = channel.recv(1024)
    print outp
```

or do this:

```
outp = ""
while channel.recv_ready():
    outp = channel.recv(1024)
print outp
```

Comment: are still getting the same Error as well ?

Comment: okay so we fixed the problem with outp not being declared. Check if the while loop is even entered by debugging or just printing inside it.

Comment: try using recv_stderr() and recv_exit_status() to figure out what went wrong. It appears that there is nothing to receive. Also look into the exec_command function maybe it works better for you. http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#exec_command

Comment: exec_command is not sequential, as i cannot run sudo on some command, so channel.send() seems correct